# change dir to newly created yeoman project from yeoman generator itself

Tags: javascript, yeoman, scaffolding, yeoman-generator, cd

I want to scaffold a project into same named directory and after generator finished with its job i want consumer to be redirected to that folder.

So I'm accepting project name as an argument: `this.argument('name', { type: String, required: false });` and then create that folder and change `destinationRoot` to it:

```
if (this.name) {
  mkdirp(this.name);
  this.destinationRoot(this.destinationPath(this.name));
}
```

After all I want to make kinda `cd this.name` at the end stage of [runContext cycle](http://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html). I tried to change `destinationRoot` to parent directory and then `cd` to to it, and it supposed to work, but it doesn't:

```
end: function () {
  if (this.name) {
    console.log('BEFORE', ls('.'))
    this.destinationRoot('..');
    console.log('AFTER', ls('.'))
    cd(this.name);
  }
},
```

Here is log:

```
BEFORE [ 'README.md', 'index.js', 'package.json', 'test.js' ]
AFTER [ 'meow' ]
```

But It doesn't work because once yeoman finish it's job I’m still in the currrent folder and not in the `meow` folder. Does anybody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeoman doesn't change directory for the user.

You might be able to do it manually by using [`process.chdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory)

Comment: does it work for you? it doesnt for me https://gist.github.com/iamstarkov/8f2daf1cf7057c88e739

Comment: Oh that's not possible as far as I know, a child process cannot change the environment of its parent.